# Graphviz ordering graph following numeric rank

Tags: plot, graph, graphviz, pagerank

How do I plot a graph in which nodes are given numeric values of importance such as PageRank ?

I would like that nodes with higher importance to be plotted, for example, higher in figure (or maybe more in the center).

I found rank property but it does not accept numeric values.

Comment: You could try to use e.g as name `"A_1"` etc. and as label: `label="1"`, so `A_1 [label="1"]`.

Comment: I tried this but plotting did not followed the labels. Could you please give a example file of your idea?

Comment: I think you should define the  the nodes and then chain the together like `A_1 -> A2 -> A3` etc and use something like `[rank=same; A_1 A-2 A_3] ` maybe you also need to define the direction  like "TB" or "LR", but please first show the code you have tried so far.